# python how to detect a phrase in a very long strings?

Tags: python, list, detect

I am trying to convert numbers from paper statements(pytesseract) and import it to excel, an example would be to find amount of money transferred by detecting "Amount" on a statement:

"......Amount: $345"

I use the following code to detect the keyword:

```
for position,letter in enumerate(huge_text):
    if letter=='A':
        if word[position+1]=='m':
            if word[position+2]=='o':
                if word[position+3]=='u':
                    if word[position+4]=='n':
                        if word[position+5]=='t':
                            print('word[position+9]'+'word[position+10]'+'word[position+11])`
```

This is obviously very cumbersome, also I don't know the length of the number so I might miss something in the process, any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

Simply select the substring: `if word[position+1:position+6]=='mount':`

But better: `if word[position:position+6]=='Amount':` directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's much more elegant!Also how do I catch the cash amount if I don't know the length of the number? It could be $1700 or $345

Comment: I would say you should use a regular expression instead. Have a look at `re` in the Python documentation. It will take care of the `Amount` issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect case for a regex:

```
import re
match = re.search(r"Amount: \$(\d+)", huge_text)
if match:
    amount = match.group(1)
```

Comment: Oh hey awesome, will look into re!

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong on so many levels and the effort you put into this abomination...

You should consider using `find()` method which returns the starting index of the given parameter inside the string.

You can use something like this

```
if(line.find("Amount")):
    # do something
```

in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the built-in [find](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_find.asp) method of strings. For finding the first occurrence:

```
pos = huge_text.find('Amount')
```

Now, `pos` is -1 if Amount was not found, it's index otherwise. To find all occurrences, you could wrap it in s `while` loop:

```
positions = []
p = 0
while p >= 0:
    p = huge_text.find('Amount', p+1)
    if p > 0:
        positions.append(p)
```

In this case, you always start the new search from the last found index. But if you want to find the amounts, you should consider [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re

amounts = re.findall(r'Amount: ?\$(\d+.?\d?)', huge_text)
```

Explanation: The parentheses show the actual pattern we want to extract (`\d+.?\d?` indicates that it is a number), the first part (`Amount: ?`) accounts for the keyword you are looking for followed by a colon and an optional space. An example:

```
import re

huge_text = 'Lorem ipsum Amount: $345 dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amount:$6351 Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu Amount: $9852 fugiat nulla pariatur.'

amounts = [float(x.strip()) for x in re.findall(r'Amount: ?\$(\d+.?\d?)', huge_text)]

# => [345.0, 6351.0, 9852.0]
```

The last step just converts the matches to numbers.

Comment: Beautiful. Will look into RE